# syntax error on `If` line

Tags: python, syntax

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def Runaaall(aaa):
  Objects9(1.0, 2.0)

def Objects9(aaa1, aaa2):
  If aaa2 != 0: print aaa1 / aaa2
```

The error I receive:

```
$ python test2.py 
  File "test2.py", line 7
    If aaa2 != 0: print aaa1 / aaa2
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm at a loss to why this error is happening.

Comment: What python tutorial are you using to learn the language?

Comment: @S.Lott: :) I guess he hasn't followed your advice here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573548/python-def-function-how-do-you-specify-the-end-of-the-function

Comment: @SilentGhost: Good point.  I rarely check to see who asks the question.  This appears to be two questions with the same bad behavior: type random stuff and hope it works.

Comment: The 'if' keyword must be lowercase. But this is a good catch that the syntax error highlighting caret points to 'aaa2' not the capital 'If', even in Python 3.12

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`if` must be written in lower case.

Furthermore,

- Write function names in lower case (see [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Python style guide).
- Write the body of an `if`-clause on a separate line.
- Though in this case you'll probably not run into trouble, be careful with [comparing floats for equality](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm).
- Since you've just started learning Python, you may want to get acquainted with writing parentheses around the arguments to `print`, since from Python 3 onwards, [print is a function](http://docs.python.org/dev/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html), not a keyword.
  To enforce this syntax in Python 2.6, you can put this at the top of your file:

  ```
  from __future__ import print_function
  ```

  Demonstration:

  ```
  >>> print 'test'
  test
  >>> from __future__ import print_function
  >>> print 'test'
    File "<stdin>", line 1
      print 'test'
                 ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  >>> print('test')
  test
  ```

  For more on `__future__` imports, see the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/__future__.html).

Comment: the last point can be achieved by using from __future__ import print_function on python 2.6

Comment: Good point, Bartosz. I updated the answer with some more information.

Answer (score 4):

It's the capital 'I' on "If".  Change it to "if" and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
def Objects9(aaa1, aaa2):
  if aaa2 != 0: print aaa1 / aaa2
```

Python keywords are case sensitive, so you must write 'if' instead of 'If', 'for' instead of 'fOR', et cetera.