# Length of hexadecimal number

Tags: python, counting

How can we get the length of a hexadecimal number in the Python language?
I tried using this code but even this is showing some error.

```
i = 0
def hex_len(a):
    if a > 0x0:
        # i = 0
        i = i + 1
        a = a/16
        return i
b = 0x346
print(hex_len(b))
```

Here I just used 346 as the hexadecimal number, but my actual numbers are very big to be counted manually.

Comment: Can you use the number of letters of the string representation?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Length of a hex number"? What are you expecting the length of `0x346` to be?

Comment: @DavidJashi - I suppose that is obvious now, having read the question again. I must have been over-thinking it.

Comment: @JustinEthier I expect the length to be 3.

Comment: Re *"showing some error"*: That is not such a big surprise. In the two lines with "a=a/16" and "return i" you used a mix of tabs and spaces. If you are lucky you may get away with that, but [the rules are complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034517/pythons-interpretation-of-tabs-and-spaces-to-indent/25471702#25471702).

Comment: As it is, there is also the runtime error *UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment*.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "hexadecimal number", and numbers do not have a length and do not contain digits in any base.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the function `hex`:

```
>>> b = 0x346
>>> hex(b)
'0x346'
>>> len(hex(b))-2
3
```

or using string formatting:

```
>>> len("{:x}".format(b))
3
```

Answer (score 7):

While using the string representation as intermediate result has some merits in simplicity it's somewhat wasted time and memory. I'd prefer a mathematical solution (returning the pure number of digits without any 0x-prefix):

```
from math import ceil, log

def numberLength(n, base=16): 
    return ceil(log(n+1)/log(base))
```

The +1 adjustment takes care of the fact, that for an exact power of your number base you need a leading "1".

Comment: "somewhat wasted time and memory"—I'm sceptical

Comment: Considering this is python I doubt the difference in resources matters. If it was code for an embedded controller, then maybe. But +1 for thinking beyond the "obvious" string-based solution.

Comment: My measurements using the timeit module gave these results: the string solution has a runtime nearly linear to the number of digits, the log solution a nearly constant one. Break even is at about 240 bit numbers. For a 32 bit number the string routine needs half the time, for a 1024 bit number the string solution needs factor 3 of the log solution. The original question mentioned **very big** numbers...

Answer (score 2):

As Ashwini wrote, the [`hex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) function does the hard work for you:

> **hex(x)**
>
> Convert an integer number (of any size) to a hexadecimal string. The result is a valid Python expression.

Answer (score 0):

This is the program to count the num of digits in hex number using recursion

```
def count_hex(n):
    ''' returns the num of digits in hex'''
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    n >>= 4
    return 1 + count_hex(n)
```

> print(count_hex(0xFFFF))

> 4

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this without converting to a string using the bit_length method:

```
def hexLen(N): 
    return (N.bit_length()+3)//4
```

*Note that his returns a length of zero when N is 0, your function would return `None` but, in reality, you still need one hex digit to represent zero. (hint: add `max(1,...)` to cover that edge case)*