Reading file, if-statement and break
What I need is read a simple text file and stop to read when a certain string matches. Text file is:

Apple
Banana
Watermelon
Pear
Apricot

My minimal "working" example
    with open("C:\\Python\\test.txt") as file:
        while line := file.readline():
            print(line.rstrip())
            if line.rstrip() == "Pear":
                break

This returns me the error message

TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Can you help me?

Your if statement includes two leading tab characters that should be spaces

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18225712/taberror-in-python-3

In Python, spaces and tabs are parts of the code.
The "TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" in Python happens when you mix tabs and spaces for indentation within the same block of code.
Python requires consistent use of either tabs or spaces for indentation for functions like, file, while, for, if. (when uses :)
Fix your spaces or tabs, and only use one of them.
with open("C:\\Python\\test.txt") as file:
    while line := file.readline():
         print(line.rstrip())
         if line.rstrip() == "Pear":
             break

For example, here I only uses 4 spaces for each indetation
