# Duplicate Frames Created When Calling a Function in a Tkinter Application

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So this is my first Python GUI project utilizing tkinter. I come from a background in R.

I decided after a review of the documentation to create a class to handle the bulk of the work. The problem appears with my incrementer functions fwd() and bck(). If I do not call these functions in the following chunk of code:

```
class App:
def __init__(self, master):
    ....
    self.total = 2
    self.fwd()
    self.bck()
```

The output of the entire code is an empty tkinter frame.

On the other hand, if I do call them, the fwd() function works as one would expect, but every time I click the back button (command = bck()), a new and identical GUI will be attached directly to the bottom of my current GUI. If I click the back button again, another GUI will pop up behind the current GUI.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import font
from tkinter import filedialog

class App: #I'm not typing what goes in this class, this way I can avoid issues with App(Frame), etc. DUCKTYPE!
def __init__(self, master):
    self.frame = Frame(master)
    self.frame.pack()
    self.master = master
    master.title("PyCCI Caste")
    self.total = 2
    self.fwd() #Need to call these at the beginning otherwise the window is minimized??? No idea why.
    self.bck() #The back button creates a duplicate window...

## +Incrementer
def fwd(self):
    self.total += 1
    print(self.total)

## -Incrementer THIS CREATES A SECOND PANED WINDOW, WHY?!
def bck(self):
    self.total += -1
    if self.total < 3:
        self.total = 2
    print(self.total)


#Body
    self.k1 = PanedWindow(self.frame, #Note: if this is not self.frame, the error: 'App' object has no attribute 'tk' is thrown
                          height=500,
                          width=750,
                          orient = VERTICAL)
    self.k1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = 1)
    self.titlefont = font.Font(size = 12,
                               weight = 'bold')
    self.boldfont = font.Font(size=8,
                              weight = 'bold')
    self.textfont = font.Font(family = 'Arial',
                              size = 10)

#Title
    self.title = PanedWindow(self.k1)
    self.k1.add(self.title, padx = 10, pady = 10)
    Label(self.title, text = "Chronic Critically Ill Patient GUI",
          font = self.titlefont,
          fg="darkslateblue").pack()

#Top row open csv window & button
    self.k2 = PanedWindow(self.k1)
    self.k1.add(self.k2)
    self.openbutton = Button(self.k2,
                             text = "Open CSV")#, command = openfile())
    self.openbutton.pack(side = LEFT,
                         padx = 30)

#Panes below buttons
    self.k3 = PanedWindow(self.k1)
    self.k1.add(self.k3)
    self.leftpane = PanedWindow(self.k3)
    self.k3.add(self.leftpane,
                width = 400,
                padx = 30,
                pady = 25,
                stretch = "first")
    self.separator = PanedWindow(self.k3,
                                 relief = SUNKEN)
    self.k3.add(self.separator,
                width=2,
                padx=1,
                pady=20)
    self.rightpane = PanedWindow(self.k3)
    self.k3.add(self.rightpane,
                width = 220,
                padx = 10,
                pady = 25,
                stretch = "never")

#Left pane patient note text frame doo-diddly
    self.ptframe = LabelFrame(self.leftpane,
                              text = "Medical Record",
                              font = self.boldfont,
                              padx = 0,
                              pady=0,
                              borderwidth = 0)
    self.ptframe.pack()
    Label(self.ptframe,
          text = "patient # of ##").pack()

#Incrementer buttons
    self.buttonframe = Frame(self.ptframe)
    self.buttonframe.pack()
    self.buttonframe.place(relx=0.97, anchor = NE)
    #Back Button
    self.button1 = Button(self.buttonframe, text = 'Back', width = 6, command = self.bck)
    self.button1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, padx = 2, pady = 2)
    #Next Button
    self.button2 = Button(self.buttonframe, text = 'Next', width = 6, command = self.fwd)
    self.button2.grid(row = 0, column = 2, padx = 2, pady = 2)

#Scrollbar!
    self.ptscroll = Scrollbar(self.ptframe)
    self.ptscroll.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
    self.pttext = Text(self.ptframe,
                       height=300,
                       width=400,
                       wrap=WORD,
                       font=self.textfont,
                       spacing1=2,
                       spacing2=2,
                       spacing3=3,
                       padx=15,
                       pady=15)
    self.pttext.pack()
    self.ptscroll.config(command=self.pttext.yview)
    self.pttext.config(yscrollcommand=self.ptscroll.set)

#Checkbuttons
    self.checkframe = LabelFrame(self.rightpane, text="Indicators",
                                 font=self.boldfont,
                                 padx = 10,
                                 pady = 10,
                                 borderwidth=0)
    self.checkframe.pack()
    self.check1 = Checkbutton(self.checkframe, text="Non-Adherence")
    self.check1.grid(row = 1,
                     column = 0,
                     sticky = W)

root = Tk()
app = App(root) ## apply the class "App" to Tk()

### Menu stuff does not need to be part of the class
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open CSV")#, command=openfile)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About")#, command=about)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

What do you folks think? If I'm missing any pertinent information here, please let me know. The difficulty I'm having is that I don't know what I don't know about Python/Tkinter yet.

Thanks, I really appreciate any insight and direction.

**Solved (thanks Bryan Oakley & TigerhawkT3):** Due to Python's use of indentation as part of its syntax, I had created a function `bck()` which, when called, includes the code for the entirety of the rest of the GUI. To solve this problem after it was pointed out, I drew heavily from:
[Python def function: How do you specify the end of the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573548/python-def-function-how-do-you-specify-the-end-of-the-function)

Comment: Please make a complete minimal example...

Comment: You have a few linefeeds after printing `self.total` within `bck`, but then the function continues, doing all manner of fun stuff. Fix your indentation (don't forget the syntax error on line 6).

Comment: Your `bck` function is clearly creating new widgets each time it is called. Why do you think it should do otherwise?

Comment: Why does the `bck` function make new widgets and the `fwd` function doesn't?

Comment: @PGT121: because `fwd` has two lines of code, neither of which creates a widget, and `bck` has a couple dozen lines of code including many lines of code that creates widgets. Perhaps you have an indentation error? Is the code after `#Panes below buttons` intended to be part of `bck`? It is, based on how you've indented the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear you have a simple indentation error. It seems like you intend for `bck` to have four lines of code, but because almost all of the remaining code is indented the same, it is all considered to be part of `bck`.

Comment: Thanks so much, Bryan. I see now, and I really appreciate your patience. 

I apologize to others for this lousy question but, as I said in the original post, I am new to Python and I don't know what I don't know.